# Changing data in a QTableView depending on the selection of a QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

I have a `QComboBox` in one of the columns of a `QTableView`. How can I change the other columns depending on what I selected in the `ComboBox`? I am using the `QComboBox` as a delegate.

Comment: To create more informative answer said please which model you use? QStandardItemModel or your own custom model?

Comment: @Chernobyl: The QStandardItemModel.

Comment: I already reproduced your code(delegate with combobox) and my solution works if I select something in combobox and confirm that by enter clicking for example. But if you want to get solution where data will be changed automatically, when you select another item in combobox(without pressing enter) then tell me it please, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately next few hours I will be offline, but I don't want left you with my probably semi-useful answer, so I decided to wrote second case too, it is longer and little more complex but I tested it, it works, tell me If you will have some questions about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 2 approaches.

- Use natural for Qt's model `itemChanged` signal.
- emit signal from your delegate and catch it inside your main window.

If your delegate is standard which means that inside `setModelData()` method you have something like:

```
QComboBox *line = static_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
QString data = line->currentText();
//...
model->setData(index, data);
```

then I think you should use just natural way. For example:

```
connect(model,&QStandardItemModel::itemChanged,[=](QStandardItem * item) {
    if(item->column() == NEEDED_COLUMN)
    {
        //you found, just get data and use it as you want
        qDebug() << item->text();
    }
});
```

I used here `C++11` (`CONFIG += c++11` to `.pro` file) and [new syntax of signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), but of course you can use old syntax if you want.

I already reproduced your code(delegate with combobox) and my solution works if I select something in combobox and confirm that by enter clicking for example. But if you want to get solution where data will be changed automatically, when you select another item in combobox(without pressing enter) then see next case:

Create special signal onside delegate:

```
signals:
    void boxDataChanged(const QString & str);
```

Create connection inside `createEditor()` method:

```
QWidget *ItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
                                    const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                    const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QComboBox *editor = new QComboBox(parent);
    connect(editor,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(QString)),this,SIGNAL(boxDataChanged(QString)));
    return editor;
}
```

And use it!

```
ItemDelegate *del = new ItemDelegate;
ui->tableView->setItemDelegate( del);
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    connect(del,&ItemDelegate::boxDataChanged,[=](const QString & str) {
            //you found, just get data and use it as you want
            qDebug() << str;
    });
```

Comment: Great answer! Your first suggestion worked fine for me, thanks a lot!